How can I use visitor and authentication middleware for the same route?
I need a screen to be accessed both by those who have logged in and by visitors, however I wanted to use auth()->user() on this page to access the data, however if I use the auth middleware it does not allow visitors on the page and if I Don't use it, I can't use auth()->user()
I'm doing a project for an online store and I made a main screen where it shows the products, the header showing the logo and if you haven't logged in, a link to register or log in, but when I log in and I'm redirected to this main page, I don't I can use auth()->user() to get the data, as the page does not have the auth:store middleware, and if I add this middleware the page is not accessed by visitors, I was thinking about using both middleware guest and auth together, but it didn't work.
How could I solve my problem so that a page can be accessed both by those who are logged in and by visitors and be able to use auth()->user()?

auth()->user() does not require a restricted route.
You can use it on any route.
I would suggest using auth()->check() to determine if the user is logged in (i.e Not guest) and then you can do something like this.
if (auth()->check()) {
    // code for logged in users only
}


In a route without auth middleware return a blade view with code like this:
    @if(!empty(Auth::user()))
         <h1>USER {{ Auth::user()->id }}</h1>
    @else
        <h1>NO USER</h1>
    @endif

If the user is authenticated (in another route), and then open this view, it will show the user id. If it's not authenticated, will show "NO USER".
